# Scipy minimize function with specific bounds (like a Excel's solver) Python

Tags: python, excel, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have some function which I solve successfully in Excel using Solver. But I don't know how to implement it in python. For example, I have this sheet in Excel.
[image: sheet example]
I have max and min value for 4 values and the values themselves. Summse (L8) its =POWER(N8-M8;2). Sumpredict (M8) its =I3+I7+I11+I15.
Val1 (F3) has formulas =I3+1,Val2 (F7) has formulas =I7+1 and etc.
In Excel's Solver I runing with this properties:

[image: Solver's properties]

That is, I want to minimize the value of Summse (L8), but control the values val 1 (F3), val 2 (F7), val 3 (F11), val 4 (F15) within the given limits, which do not participate in the Summse formula. How can I implement something like this in Python?Or Scipy can't do this?Please advise another way.
ADD NEW:
My trying do at this,but have infinite loop, because since scipy gives the same solution:(

```
import scipy.optimize 
predict1=0
predict2=0
predict3=0
predict4=0

maxval1=1
minval1=0.5
val1=predict1+1

maxval2=1
minval2=0.4
val2=predict2+1

maxval3=1
minval3=0
val3=predict3+1

maxval4=2
minval4=1
val4=predict4+1
perfectsum=0.0867614999999661
def msepredict(x):
    predictsum=x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]
    delta=(perfectsum-predictsum)**2
    return delta
while (val1>=maxval1) or (val1<=minval1) or (val2>=maxval2) or (val2<=minval2) or (val3>=maxval3) or (val3<=minval3) or (val4>=maxval4) or (val4<=minval4):
    x0=[predict1,predict2,predict3,predict4]
    res=scipy.optimize.minimize(msepredict,x0)
    print(res.x)
    predict1=res.x[0]
    predict2=res.x[1]
    predict3=res.x[2]
    predict4=res.x[3]
    val1=predict1+1
    val2=predict2+1
    val3=predict3+1
    val4=predict4+1
    predict1+=10
    predict2+=10
    predict3+=10
    predict4+=10
```

Comment: Yes, scipy has bounded optimization capability. Read through the documentation of `scipy.optimize` and try it out yourself first.

Comment: @SolarMike of course I tried and read the documentation for scipy. I attach an example code below in the post, but there I get an infinite loop, since scipy gives the same solution.